# Vector<Point2D> .add() Replacing All Existing Elements as Well As Appending

Tags: java

I am developing with java SE on NetBeans 7.3.1

I am trying to read the first two elements of each line of a CSV file, put them input a point variable of type Point2D and append each point to the end of the Point2D vector coords.  I use the following code.

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFileName));

Vector<Point2D> coords = new Vector<Point2D>();
Point2D newPoint=new Point2D.Double(20.0, 30.0);
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
     String [] subStrings = strLine.split(" ");
     System.out.print("Substrings = " + subStrings[0] + ", " + subStrings[1]);
     System.out.println();
     newPoint.setLocation(Float.parseFloat(subStrings[0]), Float.parseFloat(subStrings[1]));
     coords.add(newPoint);          
}
```

coords.add(newPoint); appends the point as required but it also replaces every existing element in coords with the new point.  How do I stop the existing elements being replaced by the new element?

Comment: Huh? That isn't supposed to happen.

Comment: You keep adding the same object to the list.  You are witnessing the expected behavior.  If you call `setLocation` on `newPoint` **after** the loop, you'll see more evidence of how object references work in Java.  To clarify: you have one list with N elements.  Each element points to the exact same object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason the values change for every Point2D in `coords` is because there's really only one object in your Vector, you've just added it to the Vector repeatedly. When you call `setLocation` you're updating that single object, and it's reflected in every reference to the object contained in the Vector.

You need to create a new Point2D each time you want to add another entry to `coords`.

Change

```
newPoint.setLocation(Float.parseFloat(subStrings[0]), Float.parseFloat(subStrings[1]));
```

to

```
newPoint=new Point2D.Double(Float.parseFloat(subStrings[0]), Float.parseFloat(subStrings[1]));
```

Comment: That worked!  Thanks very much!  I am making the transition to Java from C++.  Hence my misunderstanding.  Thanks again!